# Trouble adding 2 shapfiles in map

Tags: dictionary, shapefile

I am trying to make a map of california's rivers and lakes around San Francisco bay. 
I download the Shape file of rivers and the one for Lakes:

```
ca.rivers <- readShapeSpatial("rivs_cnrfc.shp")

ca.lakes <- readShapeSpatial("CA_Lakes.shp")
```

Then I put the map region :

```
map("state", region = c("california"), xlim=c(-122.83, -121.69), ylim=c(36.90, 38.44))
```

And I plot the rivers:

```
plot(ca.rivers, add=TRUE, xlim=c(-122.83, -121.69), ylim=c(36.90,38.44), col="grey")
```

It work pretty well but when I wanted to add the lakes it didn't work and there is no warning or errors, I put exactly the same script than for the rivers :

```
plot(ca.lakes, add=TRUE, xlim=c(-122.83, -121.69), ylim=c(36.90,38.44), col="grey")
```

Anyone get an idea? Why it doesn't work?

Comment: Perhaps it has to do with different projections, but without seeing your original files it is impossible to determine.

Comment: Yes, I found that in my CA_Lakes.shp the limits are not GPS coordonates: Bounding Box Xmin =-371325 / Ymin =-602852 / Xmax=539300 and Ymax=452742. 
But I don't kow how to determint the limits that I need ? 
I found my shapefile here: https://www.dfg.ca.gov/biogeodata/gis/clearinghouse.asp
Thanks for your help